# Play framework 2 template using method with two and more blocks of code (like Option.fold)

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0, template-engine

The documentation has an example of using `map`

```
@products.map { p =>
  @display(product = p)
}
```

Can I use `fold` like?

```
@productOpt.fold(
  <em>-<em>
){ p =>
  @display(product = p)
}
```

How should I arrange the code in the template (the above example does not work)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use fold. I think your problem is the parenthesis. Did you try with curly brackets?

```
@productOpt.fold{
  <em>-</em>
}{ p =>
  @display(product = p)
}
```

Comment: this works, but IntelliJ IDEA writes errors. I decided to use `match`.